# Why does reCaptcha return timeout-or-duplicate error?

Tags: python, django, recaptcha

I'm trying to implement Google reCaptcha v2 on a wizard form. If I complete the captcha and submit the form without having filled out the other fields,  it returns result:

```
{'success': True, 'challenge_ts': '2018-10-30T21:47:25Z', 'hostname': '127.0.0.1'}.
```

But if I fill out all the required fields so that the form is valid it returns result:

```
{'success': True, 'challenge_ts': '2018-10-30T21:47:25Z', 'hostname': '127.0.0.1'}.
{'success': False, 'error-codes': ['timeout-or-duplicate']}
[30/Oct/2018 21:47:44] "POST /register/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3912
```

rendering the form invalid, and throwing an invalid captcha error. I'm guessing that the problem is that the captcha is being validated twice. My verify captcha logic is in the form clean method, so maybe that is the problem:

```
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super(Form, self).clean()
    recaptcha_response = self.request.POST.get('g-recaptcha-response')
    url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify'
    values = {
            'secret': settings.RECAPTCHA_SECRET_KEY,
            'response': recaptcha_response
        }
    data = urllib.parse.urlencode(values).encode()
    req =  urllib.request.Request(url, data=data)
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
    result = json.loads(response.read().decode())
    print (result)
    if result['success']:
        return cleaned_data
    else:
        raise forms.ValidationError('Error.')
```

I'm wondering if it's conflicting with my done method in the view:

```
def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
    data = {k: v for form in form_list for k, v in form.cleaned_data.items()}
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?